# Derivative of Taylor Expansion of $e^x$

Tags: derivatives

$y = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ..... + \frac{x^n}{n!} $

We needed to find to derivative of this function.

I just wrote the given series is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, therefore $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are the same, but the correct  answer is $y-\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

I mean what's wrong in my method?

*I am not asking for the solution of this problem*.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $e^x$ is an *infinite* series, whereas the function above is a *finite* series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written a finite series approximation of $e^x$, not the full expansion. If you wrote the full expansion, it would differentiate to itself, but this finite series does not.